# How to merge two Data Tables with primary key constraints in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I Have two DataTables:

1. table1 (OrderId, customerID, OrderDate); primary key is `OrderId`
2. table2 (CustomerID, CustomerName, ContactName, Country); primary key is `CustomerID`

I am trying to merge them using this code:

```
table1.Merge(table2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
```

But I get an error. I also tried both overloads od merge function.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about error?

Comment: I just want two merge two tables that have primary key constraint  enabled.

Comment: Your Primary Key from Table 2 will no longer be unique if merged because a single customer ID can be associated with several Order IDs. Can you construct a DataTable with a Join?